# Lucas is late for his assassination

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I can't for the life of me get "Lucas" to spawn during the Assassination side missions. The guides say to wear the Decker gear but no matter which version I select (Decker Soldier/Decker Specialist), Lucas does not spawn near the Reactors safehouse (or anywhere else in Burns Hill). And it's getting more complicated now that I keep buying new Deckers outfits. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When this sidequest is activated, a new suit will be added to your WARDROBE.

If you are changing at a clothing store, you are not looking to purchase a new Decker suit, but to access your wardrobe: WARDROBE > SUITS > "THE DECKER"

If you wear the Decker Soldier/Decker Specialist DLC suits, Lucas will not appear.

You do not need to go all the way up to the Reactor. Once I was wearing the suit, he showed as soon as I crossed back into Burns Hill.